# Background change on app crashes my app

Tags: android, onclick, crash, onclicklistener

I'm working on an app just for fun, and im still very new to the android world. But i wanted to add a function to my app which changes the background color to black or white, and the text color to black or white aswell. But the problem is when i open the app, it immediatly crashes. This is the MainActivity.java code for the background change:

```
RelativeLayout MainActivity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button theme_White = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WhiteTheme);
    Button theme_Black = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Blacktheme);
    final RelativeLayout MainActivity = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
        theme_White.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 MainActivity.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        });

        theme_Black.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  MainActivity.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            }
        });

    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        theme_White.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView random = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.random);
            random.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }
        });

        theme_Black.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               TextView random = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.random);
               random.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
           }
        });
```

WhiteTheme is the button to change the theme to white background and black text, and Blacktheme is the button to change the theme to black background and white text. MainActivity is the id of my activity_main.xml file.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this crash?
Thanks.

[EDIT]
Android Studio now says that the methods may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' How do i fix this?

Comment: You're not even going to tell us what the error was? At a minimum you should post your logcat output.

Comment: I dont use a emulator because my computer sucks too bad. I straight up download it to my phone and start it up on there

Comment: So you have 0 debugging capabilities? Not a good route to take at all.

Comment: Yeah i guess so, but i really dont know what i can use other than my phone

Answer (score 0):

I think your app is crashing because you are not passing the context.
Try this:

```
final RelativeLayout MainActivity = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
        theme_White.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 MainActivity.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Whenever i type in `this.getResources()` the `getResources` part turns red and states: "Cannot resolve method 'getResources()'" This doesn't happen when i remove the **this** part, but... When i remove the **this** part the `getColor` part will get a line through it (sorry i forgot how that it called in english)

Comment: Then you have to call like this `MainActivity.this.getResources()`